# remote kubectl commands are not working in python

Tags: python, kubernetes, ssh, paramiko, kubectl

I am using paramiko python package to run kubectl commands on remote server. My target to send current file to kubernetes pod which runs on external server only. But `exec_command` not doing this for me. Is it I am trying in wrong way? :

```
import os
import paramiko
ssh = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('server', port, userid, password)
client.exec_command("kubectl config use-context namespace")
client.exec_command("kubectl scale statefulsets rbatch --replicas=1")
client.exec_command("kubectl cp openings.csv namespace/rbatch-0:/srv/batch/source")
```

I appreciate if anyone can guide me

Comment: Are you using the string `namespace` in your code or are you using the actual namespace you're trying to use?

Comment: @AlexW I am using actual kubectl namespace and that command its working fine and able to scale rbatch pod, but ssh and scp exec_command not working for file transfer.

Comment: What did you to to debug the problem? Did you try reading the command (error) output?

Comment: Do you know the working directory of SSH? You might want to try `./openings.csv`.  The `exec_command` returns a 3-tuple with the stdin, stdout, stderr, are you getting any messages in stdout or stderr that would help debug?

Comment: @AlexW When referring to data files, `openings.csv` and `./openings.csv` are the same. The `./` makes difference when executing files only.

Comment: Really what I meant was that I would try to use a fully-qualified file name but yes if the working directory already has the openings.csv file it would make no difference

Comment: does the file `openings.csv` live on the local server or the remote one?

Comment: @Ohmen its local one

Comment: @AlexW I have tried in "./openings" as well.

Comment: You have to copy your local file to the remote server first before you can use it on the remote server inside the SSH session. You could use something like `rsync` for this task.